# How do I create a list as a dictionary entry for a specific key in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am iterating through a file looking for certain attributes in each line, and if the line matches I want to insert it as an item in a list for a particular dictionary key.

For example:

```
list_of_names = ['aaron', 'boo', 'charlie']
for name in list_of_names
    if color contains 'a':
        #add here: add to list in dict['has_a']
print dict['has_a']
```

Should print ['aaron', 'charlie'].

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm not sure how else to create multiple entries for a key in a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python's `defaultdict` for this purpose. It will automatically generate a list as a default value for the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
list_of_names = ['aaron', 'boo', 'charlie']
for name in list_of_names:
    if  'a' in name:
        mydict['has_a'].append(name)
print mydict['has_a']
```

Output:

```
['aaron', 'charlie']
```

---

The OP has indicated in a comment that he wants heterogenous values in his dictionary. In that case a `defaultdict` may not be appropriate and instead he should just special case those two cases.

```
# Initialize our dictionary with list values for the two special cases.
mydict = {'has_a' : [], 'has_b' : []}
list_of_names = ['aaron', 'boo', 'charlie']
for name in list_of_names:
    if  'a' in name:
        mydict['has_a'].append(name)
    # When not in a special case, just use the dictionary like normal to assign values.
print mydict['has_a']
```

Comment: I'd rather not do this as many of my other keys refer to booleans rather than lists. I only need 2 lists in my dictionary.

Comment: @Michi, In that case, just add the two special cases into your loop. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good use case for the `setdefault` method of the `dict` object:

```
d = dict()
for name in list_of_names:
  if 'a' in name:
    d.setdefault("has_a", []).append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `key` function to get list of keys and check if adding is needed. Then append as always.

`list_of_names = ['aaron', 'boo', 'charlie']
has_dictionary = {}
for name in list_of_names:
    if name.find('a') != -1:
       if 'has_a' not in has_dictionary.keys():
          has_dictionary['has_a'] = []
       has_dictionary['has_a'].append(name)
print(has_dictionary['has_a'])`